# Reopen a closed question after a major edit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77582/moving-compiled-assembly-code-to-the-boot-sector-of-a-usb-device?noredirect=1#comment113732_77582) and it got closed. I believe that the concerns cited were dealt with very clearly in the original question and that the people who closed it simply did not read past the title, but I have re-writen it completely to address this. Is the re-writen version acceptable, or do I still need to do something to it?

If I still need to work on it, are there any suggestions? Does it need to moved to a different site as some comments have said about the original question?

Answer (score 3):

In general, edited closed questions get put into the review queue and active high-rep users are encouraged to look at them and consider voting to reopen.

In this case, I've reopened it based on the edit.