# Missing feedback why a question is kept on hold

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

**(Question adapted according to the information given by Michael Homer)**

From [this answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1274/216004) I did believe that "*edited closed questions get put into the review queue*", and Michael Homer's comment confirms this. However, those question still look like they were forgotten after the reopening was rejected.

This leads to users waiting for one day and finally posting the same question anew with identical content, which doesn't seem useful neither for the user nor for the platform.

So either the closing banner should be updated to "The question remains on hold for this and that reason" or the ones voting to leave it closed should be encouraged to give a commentary on their vote. Maybe there are better ideas, but the readers shouldn't be left unclear of the status of the question, I think.

(*Background, if you care: I stumbled over [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386854/url-filtering-with-input-mac-addresses) and thought I've seen it before. And found [this identical question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386689/url-filtering-based-on-input-mac-address). This has been closed in the first version for good reasons, edited after an hour, then flagged by a single user to reopen, but still on hold for 15 hours, so finally the user posted the question anew (not flagged to close, getting helpful reactions and even an upvote). It seems that it's easier to post a new question with same content than to struggle to reopen the old one. I don't want to argue about this specific question, just about the feedback mechanism. In my eyes, even a user with a bad question deserves to receive a reaction like "still not good enough" or "reopened" in a time not too much longer than the time to close it.*

Comment: That question has been through the reopen queue and left closed (3x leave closed, 1x reopen). Edits on closed questions do automatically put them into the queue.

Comment: It may also be relevant that the question [has been edited *more* after going through the queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386689/timeline), which doesn't put it back in.

Comment: @MichaelHomer You mean if someone does an insufficient edit on a closed question, some people give their vote to keep it closed, but then comes a good edit while the queue is still open, the given votes still count?

Comment: My understanding is that once something is cleared from (any) queue, it can't go back in again until the votes have aged away. 3x "Leave Closed" (or 3x "Leave Open") removes the entry from the queue, and a further edit or vote won't put it back. The reopen votes remain live though, for someone who visited the question directly.

Comment: For me, this is one more reason to change the handling of a failed reopening: Not only better feedback (was rejected again after the edit, perhaps new reason for closing), but also a second chance to be reopened. But on the other hand a mechanism is required to prevent a question to be reopened over and over by trivial edits.

Comment: @MichaelHomer FWIW, I sometimes notice questions in the reopen queue that have been pushed there with only minor edits (spelling etc.). Rejecting the reopening of these questions would basically sentence them to eternally being closed... unless someone manually votes to reopen them later. This is a bit wrong.

Comment: How about a question is kept open, mainly because it ends up being marked all too fast as a duplicate answer. Take my own question from yesterday as an example:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387740/make-awk-print-the-line-that-match-a-variable-and-the-next-n-lines-and-use-a-var?noredirect=1#comment690183_387740 . This has already been marked as a duplicate answer. I can see that there are elements that are related, but the duplicate answer does not answer my initial question. As a beginner in unix I find that epxert-users have tendency of marking questions as duplicate a bit too fast

Comment: Am I correct that this is still an issue?